# How to make a multi line array in pascal

Tags: arrays, delphi, pascal, freepascal

I made a basic array like as shown below. Can I make array per line? without double quotes and commas?

```
 var
  Month: array [1 .. 5] of string = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May');
begin
  Write(Month[4]);
  Readln;
end.
```

That might be like this

```
Month: array [1 .. 5] of string = (
January
February
March
April
May
)

begin
  Write(Month[4]);
  Readln;
end.
```

regards.

Comment: No, Pascal type system doesn't allow this bedlam

Comment: is that any alternative if i will to use a thousand of array?

Comment: If you have very large string set, store them in text file and load into TStringList or array

Comment: thanks, i'll try it :)

Comment: You could get quite close to what you seem to want by declaring Month as an enumeration and using GetEnumName from the TypInfo unit to return a string.

Comment: @MartynA: But declaring a separate enum for each set of strings just to avoid a few quotes (but not the commas) doesn't make things easier. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Neither, from my pov, does wanting to do it without commas or quotes.

Comment: @MartynA: Indeed. So the first comment by @ MBo is the only one that makes sense, IMO.

Comment: @MartynA The other problem with enums is _no spaces allowed_.

Comment: @CraigYoung:  Thanks, but I don't think that's a problem with enums so much as with the OP's expectations.

Comment: @MartynA Agreed (and please don't think I assumed you would expect spaces to work). Comment was more for OP's benefit if he tries using enums. I may be wrong, but I don't think he contemplated the impact of spaces in his strings yet.

Comment: @ArifIkhsanudin Delphi allows you to put each string on a separate line. But you must still provide the ***single*** (as in `'`) quotes and comma-separators. (Double quotes look like this: `"` at each end of the sting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you want is not possible. The syntax doesn't allow it.

You can do the following:

```
const
  Month: array[1..5] of string = (
    'January',
    'February', 
    'March', 
    'April',
    'May'
  );
```

But not what you want. Line endings (or any other whitespace) are not proper separators, and strings must always be enclosed in single quotes, and array elements (of a const array) must separated by commas.